# How can i use Laraval Lang with JS confirm model?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-8

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.ask').on('click', function () {
var message = "{{ __('so.fields.are-you-sure') }}";
     confirm(message);
}
</script>
```

I want to show Yes, No text which is in Lang file on confirm button. How can I do this? Which code do I need to add?

Or is this possible with jQuery?

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials that show exactly how to achive that. Just google it and you will see how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works, just make sure that the translation exists
according to the attached snippet it should be found in
`en/so/fields.php` file  *- en is the language dir as example*

and contains the index

```
return [
    'are-you-sure' => 'Are you Sure!',
];
```

**But, if you are asking about localizing the `confirm` buttons**
this method depends on the language of web browser,
not your preferred language

instead of using `confirm` you can use   [jQuery UI Dialog's modal](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation) confirmation

so you can translate the buttons & customize the dialog as you like.